# Dict python in loop Json gets just the last element

Tags: python, json, dictionary, element

[image: Bot telegram with buttons]Hi, i would like to create buttons on my telegram bot, which depend by the list '["Los Angeles","New York"]'. I have problem with the python dict, when i insert it in a loop, json gets just the last element (New York). Someone can explain me why?

```
import json
import time
from pprint import pprint
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
bot = telepot.Bot("token")
lista = ["Los Angeles","New York"]
for i in lista:
    dict = {"text": i}
    print(dict)
keyboard = {"keyboard": [[dict]]}


def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)

    if content_type == "text":
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, msg["text"], reply_markup=keyboard)


MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Keys in a Python dictionary (or any key/value data structure in any language) are unique, so every time you map a value to a key it gets mutated. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Strongly advise against using ‘dict’ as a variable name as this will override the builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others in comments, it is strongly advised NOT to use a [builtin name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) as a variable name (for example `dict` in the question code) as it can [cause issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56927722/1589191#comment100396761_56927722) in [other parts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39971064/1589191) of code that depend on it. In the snippet below, I have used the name `listb` instead of `dict`.

---

I think what you want is this:

```
lista = ["Los Angeles","New York"]
listb = []
for i in lista:
    listb.append({"text": i})
    print(listb)
keyboard = {"keyboard": [listb]}
```

**Explanation:**

This line: `dict = {"text": i}` does not add a key to `dict`, it points `dict` variable to an entirely new dictionary and discards old value. So only the last value is retained.

In this particular case, the Telegram API expects a list of multiple dictionaries  each with the key `"text"` in that place.

Comment: I would strongly recommend not to use `dict` as a variable name for a list.

Comment: @NomadMonad Fixed(1). (I guess my comment saying this was deleted by somebody?)