# Tabulate Python dict

Tags: python, json, bots, telegram

i'm working to create a keyboard on a telegram bot. I would like to create some buttons. I have a problem, i would to create create a sliding keyboard that goes down. There is a problem, with json you can create it by the code n1, but in python i cant find a solution. So how can i convert 'lista = ["New York","Los Angeles","Miami","Toronto","Berlin","Rome"]'in json (code n1)?

```
#code n1 (JSON)
{"keyboard": [[{"text": "New York"}, {"text": "Los Angeles"}],
                         [{"text": "Miami"}, {"text": "Toronto"}],
                         [{"text": "Berlin"}, {"text": "Rome"}]]}


#code2
import json
import time
from pprint import pprint
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
bot = telepot.Bot("token")
lista = ["New York","Los Angeles","Miami","Toronto","Berlin","Rome"]
kdict = []
for i in lista:
    kdict.append({"text": i})
    print(kdict)
keyboard = {"keyboard": [kdict]}



def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)

    if content_type == "text":
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, msg["text"], reply_markup=keyboard)


MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: You already asked the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278371/dict-python-in-loop-json-gets-just-the-last-element

Comment: No. The issue is different. I want to put the elements of the dict in different lines as in the json code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using blhsing answer

```
#code n1 (JSON)
{"keyboard": [[{"text": "New York"}, {"text": "Los Angeles"}],
                         [{"text": "Miami"}, {"text": "Toronto"}],
                         [{"text": "Berlin"}, {"text": "Rome"}]]}


#code2
import json
import time
from pprint import pprint
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
bot = telepot.Bot("token")
lista = ["New York","Los Angeles","Miami","Toronto","Berlin","Rome"]

seq = iter(lista)

keyboard = {"keyboard": [[{'text': i} for i in pair] for pair in zip(seq, seq)]}



def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)

    if content_type == "text":
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, msg["text"], reply_markup=keyboard)


MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

To pair items in a list you can create an iterator from the list, zip the iterator with itself, and use a list comprehension to iterator through the zipped pairs:

```
seq = iter(lista)
[[{'text': i} for i in pair] for pair in zip(seq, seq)]
```

This returns:

```
[[{'text': 'New York'}, {'text': 'Los Angeles'}],
 [{'text': 'Miami'}, {'text': 'Toronto'}],
 [{'text': 'Berlin'}, {'text': 'Rome'}]]
```

You can then convert it into JSON using `json.dumps`.

Comment: Sorry, i havent understand where have i to put the code that you sent me...

Comment: It means that you can replace the lines from `kdict = []` to `keyboard = {"keyboard": [kdict]}` with the 2 lines of `seq = iter(lista)` and `keyboard = {"keyboard": [[{'text': i} for i in pair] for pair in zip(seq, seq)]}`.